# Error when rotating screen with Applescript

Tags: debugging, applescript

I use the following script to rotate my portable monitor automatically.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "ASUS MB16AC"
    click radio button "Display" of tab group 1
    click pop up button "Rotation:" of tab group 1
    click menu item "90°" of menu 1 of pop up button "Rotation:" of tab group 1
    set success to 0
    repeat until success is equal to 1
        delay 1
        try
            tell sheet 1
                click button "Confirm"
                set success to 1
            end tell
        on error errText
            log errText
            delay 1
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

When calling the script with `osascript` on Terminal, I get the following error message, but the code does the job anyway.

```
System Events got an error: Can’t get sheet 1 of window "ASUS MB16AC" of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.
```

How can this error be avoided?

－－－－－

## Additional Information:

The script worked *without error* when run under the `Script Editor`.

The error only came up when I execute the script from Terminal using `osascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the sheet exists before trying to click the button, like so:

```
repeat until success is equal to 1
    delay 1
    if exists sheet 1 then
        try
            tell sheet 1
                click button "Confirm"
                set success to 1
            end tell
        on error errText
            log errText
            delay 1
        end try
    end if
end repeat
```

With that `if exists` block you probably won't even need the try block.

Comment: How does the `if exists` block and `try` block differ in functionality? Seems pretty much the same to me (except `try` alone gave rise to the weird error....)

Comment: The `try` block catches errors after they occur: it executes the command blindly, and gives us a chance to deal with problems if something goes wrong. the `if exists` block looks to see if the object we're trying to send a command to is there before we send the command, thus preventing an error from getting thrown in the first place.

Comment: So the above error is due to a timing problem? (The code looking for `sheet 1` before it exists?) The `repeat` block seems to point to such trial and error as well. (Try and see if the button is there until you succeed...)

Comment: Exactly. It may take a popup menu or a sheet half a second to run through its constructor and be displayed (barely noticeable in human terms, but an eternity in computer time). Such things usually send out notifications when they are fully instantiated, but AppleScript isn't designed to look for those notifications, so it has to loop, wait, and test the waters.

Answer (score 1):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is how I would code it, and this works for me, as is, in **macOS High Sierra**:

```
if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window 1
    click pop up button 1 of tab group 1
    click menu item 2 of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of tab group 1
    repeat until exists sheet 1
        delay 0.5
    end repeat
    click button 1 of sheet 1
    delay 0.1
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans included *error* handling does not contain any additional *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

Comment: Your script gave rise to a similar error on my side:

error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu 1 of pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process \"System Preferences\". Invalid index." number -1719 from menu 1 of pop up button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"

Comment: @Sati What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: macOs Mojave 10.14.2